# text box to be of fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when you reduce the browser window you will see a different lay out....
when you scroll down the search text box goes up and its not fixed so its not visible...
how to make the search text box as fixed when you scroll down....
i used the code from another example but the problem is when i implement with my new code its not working....
i am trying to work with the data tables search box....
don't know whats wrong in my code....

http://jsfiddle.net/bz2C4/11/

```
$(function() {
        var search = $('.dataTables_filter').detach();
        $('.page-title').before(search);
        search.css('margin-left','0');

        var div = $('.dataTables_filter');
                var start = $(div).offset().top;

                $.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
                    var p = $(window).scrollTop();
                    $(div).css('position', ((p) > start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
                    $(div).css('top', ((p) > start) ? '0px' : '');
                });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic issue is css related. Block elements like `DIV` will automatically fill all available width when position is not set to `absolute` or `fixed`. Once you use one of those positions you need to define width if it is important to your layout.

I suggest you toggle a class that has all the fixed position and width rules instead of setting `position` inline with `css()` method. Try using `width:100%`

Comment: thanks for your reply in my fiddle in style tags i have already included my css but still its not working <style>
 
 .dataTables_filter{
  position: static; text-align: center;
  }
 
  .page-body {
   position:relative;
  }

Comment: but add another set of rules for `.dataTables_filter.fixed` then toggle the class `fixed` on it using `addClass('fixed')`/`removeClass('fixed')`

Comment: even adding `width` to exisitng rule will help. Can do live adjustments in browser console and see what I mean